# How to make images inside a box responsive CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I am facing a problem in modifying a website template. I have four images in total and I want them to appear as one in the first row centralized and the other three in the second row. 
The template code by default had an arrangement to place three images side by side within boxes, but for placing only one image, how do I align the image to the center?
Here is the fiddle link :

https://jsfiddle.net/ntbmop1b/1/

I tried `position : relative` but it wasn't responsive. 
Position relative trial :

```
<div class="s-12 m-6 l-4 margin-bottom" style="position:relative; left:18em;">
  <div class="box">
   <h4 style="text-align:center;"><strong>Akshay Aravindan</strong></h4><br>
    <img src="img/del1.jpg" style="height:300px; ">
   </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Just curious, if the media queries for m-x and l-x are missed out by mistake ??? because even when I move to a smaller screen s-12 m-6 l-4 always shows up the size of l-4

Comment: Yeah missed out by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added float:none and margin:0 auto

```css
.size-960 .line {
  margin:0 auto;
  max-width:55em;  /*fixes width of the template's main page layout*/
  padding:0 0.625em;
 
}
.size-1140 .line {
  margin:0 auto;
  max-width:71.25em;
  padding:0 0.625em;
}
.size-960.align-content-left .line,.size-1140.align-content-left .line {margin-left:0;}
form {line-height:1.4em;}
nav {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  background:#262626;
}
.line::after, nav::after, .center::after, .box::after, .margin::after {
  clear:both;
  content:".";
  display:block;
  height:0;
  line-height:0;
  visibility:hidden;
}
.box {
  background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  display:block;
  padding:1.25em;
  width:100%;
  }
.margin-bottom {margin-bottom:1.25em;}
.s-1, .s-2,.s-five,.s-3, .s-4, .s-5, .s-6, .s-7, .s-8, .s-9, .s-10, .s-11, .s-12, .m-1, .m-2, .m-five, .m-3, .m-4, .m-5, .m-6, .m-7, .m-8, .m-9, .m-10, .m-11, .m-12, .l-1, .l-2, .l-five, .l-3, .l-4, .l-5, .l-6, .l-7, .l-8, .l-9, .l-10, .l-11, .l-12 {
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}
.l-offset-1 {margin-left:8.3333%;}
.l-offset-2 {margin-left:16.6666%;}
.l-offset-five {margin-left:16.6666%;}
.l-offset-3 {margin-left:25%;}
.l-offset-4 {margin-left:33.3333%;}
.l-offset-5 {margin-left:41.6666%;}
.l-offset-6 {margin-left:50%;}
.l-offset-7 {margin-left:58.3333%;}
.l-offset-8 {margin-left:66.6666%;}
.l-offset-9 {margin-left:75%;}
.l-offset-10 {margin-left:83.3333%;}
.l-offset-11 {margin-left:91.6666%;}
.l-offset-12 {margin-left:100%;} 
.s-1 {width:8.3333%;}
.s-2 {width:16.6666%;}
.s-five {width:16.6666%;}
.s-3 {width:25%;}
.s-4 {width:33.3333%;}
.s-5 {width:41.6666%;}
.s-6 {width:50%;}
.s-7 {width:58.3333%;}
.s-8 {width:66.6666%;}
.s-9 {width:75%;}
.s-10 {width:83.3333%;}
.s-11 {width:91.6666%;}
.s-12 {width:100%;}
.margin > .s-1,.margin > .s-2,.margin > .s-five,.margin > .s-3,.margin > .s-4,.margin > .s-5,.margin > .s-6,.margin > .s-7,.margin > .s-8,.margin > .s-9,.margin > .s-10,.margin > .s-11,.margin > .s-12,
.margin > .m-1,.margin > .m-2,.margin > .m-five,.margin > .m-3,.margin > .m-4,.margin > .m-5,.margin > .m-6,.margin > .m-7,.margin > .m-8,.margin > .m-9,.margin > .m-10,.margin > .m-11,.margin > .m-12,
.margin > .l-1,.margin > .l-2,.margin > .l-five,.margin > .l-3,.margin > .l-4,.margin > .l-5,.margin > .l-6,.margin > .l-7,.margin > .l-8,.margin > .l-9,.margin > .l-10,.margin > .l-11,.margin > .l-12 {padding:0 0.625em;}
.m-1 {width:8.3333%;}
.m-2 {width:16.6666%;}
.m-five {width:20%;}
.m-3 {width:25%;}
.m-4 {width:33.3333%;}
.m-5 {width:41.6666%;}
.m-6 {width:50%;}
.m-7 {width:58.3333%;}
.m-8 {width:66.6666%;}
.m-9 {width:75%;}
.m-10 {width:83.3333%;}
.m-11 {width:91.6666%;}
.m-12 {width:100%;}
.l-1 {width:8.3333%;}
.l-2 {width:16.6666%;}
.l-five {width:20%;}
.l-3 {width:25%;}
.l-4 {width:33.3333%;}
.l-5 {width:41.6666%;}
.l-6 {width:50%;}
.l-7 {width:58.3333%;}
.l-8 {width:66.6666%;}
.l-9 {width:75%;}
.l-10 {width:83.3333%;}
.l-11 {width:91.6666%;}
.l-12 {width:100%;}
.right {float:right;}
```

```html
<div class="line">
            <div class="margin">
            <h2 style="color:#000;text-align:center;"><strong>Technical</strong></h2>
            <h3 style="color:#000;text-align:center;"><strong>UDG</strong></h3>
               <div class="s-12 m-6 l-4 margin-bottom" style="float:none;margin:0 auto;">
                  <div class="box">
                     <h4 style="text-align:center;"><strong>John</strong></h4><br>
                     <img src="img/del1.jpg" style="height:300px; ">
                  </div>
               </div>
                       
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="line">
            <div class="margin">
            <h3 style="color:#000;text-align:center;"><strong>General Administrators</strong></h3>
                <div class="s-12 m-6 l-4 margin-bottom">
                  <div class="box">
                     <h4 style="text-align:center;"><strong>Ashley</strong></h4><br>
                     <img src="img/sponsor3.jpg" style="height:268px; ">
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="s-12 m-6 l-4 margin-bottom">
                  <div class="box">
                     <h4 style="text-align:center;"><strong>Susan</strong></h4><br>
                     <img src="img/del3.jpg" style="height:300px; ">
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="s-12 m-6 l-4 margin-bottom">
                  <div class="box">
                     <h4 style="text-align:center;"><strong>Sherley</strong></h4><br>
                     <img src="img/del4.jpeg" style="height:300px; ">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: Works to center align. Thanks :)

Comment: How about if I needed to align two images in a row?

Comment: Float right and left makes the two images get aligned on two sides with gap inbetween. What if I wanted two images to be aligned in center together responsively/

Comment: means you want to images in row with center align?

Comment: Yes.All images with text inside a div.

Comment: I want two images in a row instead of three center aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, to center an element inside it's parent container horizontally you would set the margin on the sides of the element to auto, so that the element is always equally distant from parent walls on sides.

```
.centered-element {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**EDIT**: Things you need to change in your html and css in order to center your div with class name 'box':

Parent container, the one that looks like this now:

```
<div class="s-12 m-6 l-4 margin-bottom" style="margin: 0 auto;">
```

Needs to change to this:

```
<div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12 margin-bottom">
```

In your css files, change the

```
.box {
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
display: block;
padding: 1.25em;
width: 100%;
}
```

to

```
.box {
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
display: block;
padding: 1.25em;
width: 60%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: because you added "margin: 0 auto;" to the parent element (which by the way has wrong classes anyway) instead of the element you are trying to center. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Normally to make responsive images, most of the responsive frameworks make images as a block level element and set its max-width to be less than 100% (To avoid the images overflowing the container DIV)

Then to make the div centered you can use margin: 0 auto;

So image responsive class will be as follows

```
.img-responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```css
.size-960 .line {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 55em;
  /*fixes width of the template's main page layout*/
  padding: 0 0.625em;
}
.img-responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.size-1140 .line {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 71.25em;
  padding: 0 0.625em;
}
.size-960.align-content-left .line,
.size-1140.align-content-left .line {
  margin-left: 0;
}
form {
  line-height: 1.4em;
}
nav {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #262626;
}
.line::after,
nav::after,
.center::after,
.box::after,
.margin::after {
  clear: both;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.box {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  display: block;
  padding: 1.25em;
  width: 100%;
}
.margin-bottom {
  margin-bottom: 1.25em;
}
.s-1,
.s-2,
.s-five,
.s-3,
.s-4,
.s-5,
.s-6,
.s-7,
.s-8,
.s-9,
.s-10,
.s-11,
.s-12,
.m-1,
.m-2,
.m-five,
.m-3,
.m-4,
.m-5,
.m-6,
.m-7,
.m-8,
.m-9,
.m-10,
.m-11,
.m-12,
.l-1,
.l-2,
.l-five,
.l-3,
.l-4,
.l-5,
.l-6,
.l-7,
.l-8,
.l-9,
.l-10,
.l-11,
.l-12 {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.l-offset-1 {
  margin-left: 8.3333%;
}
.l-offset-2 {
  margin-left: 16.6666%;
}
.l-offset-five {
  margin-left: 16.6666%;
}
.l-offset-3 {
  margin-left: 25%;
}
.l-offset-4 {
  margin-left: 33.3333%;
}
.l-offset-5 {
  margin-left: 41.6666%;
}
.l-offset-6 {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
.l-offset-7 {
  margin-left: 58.3333%;
}
.l-offset-8 {
  margin-left: 66.6666%;
}
.l-offset-9 {
  margin-left: 75%;
}
.l-offset-10 {
  margin-left: 83.3333%;
}
.l-offset-11 {
  margin-left: 91.6666%;
}
.l-offset-12 {
  margin-left: 100%;
}
.s-1 {
  width: 8.3333%;
}
.s-2 {
  width: 16.6666%;
}
.s-five {
  width: 16.6666%;
}
.s-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
.s-4 {
  width: 33.3333%;
}
.s-5 {
  width: 41.6666%;
}
.s-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
.s-7 {
  width: 58.3333%;
}
.s-8 {
  width: 66.6666%;
}
.s-9 {
  width: 75%;
}
.s-10 {
  width: 83.3333%;
}
.s-11 {
  width: 91.6666%;
}
.s-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
.margin > .s-1,
.margin > .s-2,
.margin > .s-five,
.margin > .s-3,
.margin > .s-4,
.margin > .s-5,
.margin > .s-6,
.margin > .s-7,
.margin > .s-8,
.margin > .s-9,
.margin > .s-10,
.margin > .s-11,
.margin > .s-12,
.margin > .m-1,
.margin > .m-2,
.margin > .m-five,
.margin > .m-3,
.margin > .m-4,
.margin > .m-5,
.margin > .m-6,
.margin > .m-7,
.margin > .m-8,
.margin > .m-9,
.margin > .m-10,
.margin > .m-11,
.margin > .m-12,
.margin > .l-1,
.margin > .l-2,
.margin > .l-five,
.margin > .l-3,
.margin > .l-4,
.margin > .l-5,
.margin > .l-6,
.margin > .l-7,
.margin > .l-8,
.margin > .l-9,
.margin > .l-10,
.margin > .l-11,
.margin > .l-12 {
  padding: 0 0.625em;
}
.m-1 {
  width: 8.3333%;
}
.m-2 {
  width: 16.6666%;
}
.m-five {
  width: 20%;
}
.m-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
.m-4 {
  width: 33.3333%;
}
.m-5 {
  width: 41.6666%;
}
.m-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
.m-7 {
  width: 58.3333%;
}
.m-8 {
  width: 66.6666%;
}
.m-9 {
  width: 75%;
}
.m-10 {
  width: 83.3333%;
}
.m-11 {
  width: 91.6666%;
}
.m-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
.l-1 {
  width: 8.3333%;
}
.l-2 {
  width: 16.6666%;
}
.l-five {
  width: 20%;
}
.l-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
.l-4 {
  width: 33.3333%;
}
.l-5 {
  width: 41.6666%;
}
.l-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
.l-7 {
  width: 58.3333%;
}
.l-8 {
  width: 66.6666%;
}
.l-9 {
  width: 75%;
}
.l-10 {
  width: 83.3333%;
}
.l-11 {
  width: 91.6666%;
}
.l-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div class="margin">
    <h2 style="color:#000;text-align:center;"><strong>Technical</strong></h2>
    <h3 style="color:#000;text-align:center;"><strong>UDG</strong></h3>
    <div class="s-12 m-6 l-4 margin-bottom">
      <div class="box">
        <h4 style="text-align:center;"><strong>John</strong></h4>
        <br>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="line">
  <div class="margin">
    <h3 style="color:#000;text-align:center;"><strong>General Administrators</strong></h3>
    <div class="s-12 m-6 l-4 margin-bottom">
      <div class="box">
        <h4 style="text-align:center;"><strong>Ashley</strong></h4>
        <br>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x300">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="s-12 m-6 l-4 margin-bottom">
      <div class="box">
        <h4 style="text-align:center;"><strong>Susan</strong></h4>
        <br>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x300" style="height:300px; ">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="s-12 m-6 l-4 margin-bottom">
      <div class="box">
        <h4 style="text-align:center;"><strong>Sherley</strong></h4>
        <br>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x300">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```